# Removing specific log events from CloudWatchLogs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I looked through [the documentation of CloudWatch Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/WhatIsCloudWatchLogs.html), but I could not find any method to manually remove partial data from a `log stream`.

The only way to remove data is to:

- Remove the `log stream`, but that will remove all data (not just the
  data we want to remove)
- Set the retention policy to a smaller time
  window, so that the log events older than X time will be deleted.
  This also removes more than we'd like to remove.

Does anyone have experience with removing specific log records?

Comment: Are you looking for someone to tell you there's a secret undocumented API call?

Comment: Hah, that would be nice too. But no, I'm wondering if someone already found a work-around (exporting logs, removing what needs to be removed and then reuploading them as new logs, etc. etc.)

Comment: Unfortunately, as of today, you cannot delete a single log event from CloudWatch log stream, the alternative will be using Lambda functions: set a Lambda function trigger, filter all logs, then write the remaining logs to a new log group/stream, then delete the original log stream. This document uses the CloudTrail event as an example: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html#LambdaFunctionExample

Comment: You'll get better (or any) answers if you explain _why_ you want to delete log records. Copying will work, but it's not very optimal, and it works best if you do it on an ongoing basis (versus "oops, we wrote a password into the log, let's delete those rows"). If your use case is the latter, you'd be better off using Elasticsearch as your log repository, because it will let you select and individually delete documents.(and you might be interested in [this article](https://www.kdgregory.com/index.php?page=aws.loggingPipeline) that I wrote on how to set up an ES-based logging pipeline).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comment of user `ronald8192` is indeed the reality:

> Unfortunately, as of today, you cannot delete a single log event from CloudWatch log stream, the alternative will be using Lambda functions: set a Lambda function trigger, filter all logs, then write the remaining logs to a new log group/stream, then delete the original log stream.